# Need help formatting output coming from multiple computers

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

Is there a way to get the desired output shown below? Basically, I'm looking if User1 exists on given list of computers.

Script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2 -ScriptBlock {
    Get-LocalUser
}
```

Output:

```
Name                 Enabled Description                                                         
----                 ------- -----------                                                         
Administrator        False   Built-in account for administering the computer/domain              
DefaultAccount       False   A user account managed by the system.                               
Guest                False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain            
User1                True    User 1
```

Desired Output:

```
Name                 Computer 
----                 ------- 
User1                Computer 1 
User1                Computer 2
```

Comment: Use `Get-LocalUser -Name User1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Localuser` allows to search for a specify user or even use wildcards via the [`-Name` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1#-name). To get the desired output you can then pipe the result of `Invoke-Command` to `Select-Object` using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties#:%7E:text=The%20calculated%20property%20is%20defined,value%2C%20and%20optional%20formatting%20information.) to have the `Computer` property based on the value of the `PSComputerName` property.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1, Computer2 -ScriptBlock {
    Get-LocalUser -Name User1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} | Select-Object Name, @{ N='Computer'; E='PSComputerName' }
```

Comment: `E='PSComputerName'` will do (and be faster) :)

Comment: i'm not getting any output, it takes me to new prompt

Comment: @Rod did you somehow missed to provide an argument to the parameter? update the code you're currently using otherwise I would be just guessing

Comment: My apologies, copy and paste foils me again!